# Mule ESB REST testing (curl and Eclipse)

Tags: java, rest, testing, mule

I have the following mule flow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <json:object-to-json-transformer name="Object_to_JSON" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <flow doc:name="HelloWorldFlow1" name="HelloWorldFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" contentType="application/json" path="mule/getBalance"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.HashMap"/>
    <choice doc:name="Determine Bank" >
            <when expression="#[message.payload.get('uid') == 'ABC']">
                <set-payload value="When ABC case" doc:name="Fin Acct"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-payload value="#['Default case, payload:  ' + payload + ', payload.get(\047uid\047): ' + payload.get('uid')]" doc:name="SOF Bank"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

and I test it as follows:

```
C:\curl>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i -d @input2.txt http://localh
ost:8081/mule/getBalance
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 18:53:06 -0700
Server: Mule EE Core Extensions/3.5.0
Content-Type: application/json
X-MULE_SESSION: rO0ABXNyACNvcmcubXVsZS5zZXNzaW9uLkRlZmF1bHRNdWxlU2Vzc2lvbi7rdtEW
7GGKAwAFWgAFdmFsaWRMAA1mbG93Q29uc3RydWN0dAAmTG9yZy9tdWxlL2FwaS9jb25zdHJ1Y3QvRmxv
bd0NvbnN0cnVjdDtMAAJpZHQAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3RyaW5nO0wACnByb3BlcnRpZXN0AA9MamF2YS91
dGlsL01hcDtMAA9zZWN1cml0eUNvbnRleHR0ACdMb3JnL211bGUvYXBpL3NlY3VyaXR5L1NlY3VyaXR5
Q29udGV4dDt4cAFwdAAkYzI3OGM3NjAtMTA3OS0xMWU0LTlmYTctMDAyMTVlNmIzZDkwc3IAJWphdmEu
dXRpbC5Db2xsZWN0aW9ucyRTeW5jaHJvbml6ZWRNYXAbc/kJS0s5ewMAAkwAAW1xAH4AA0wABW11dGV4
dAASTGphdmEvbGFuZy9PYmplY3Q7eHBzcgAkb3JnLm11bGUudXRpbC5DYXNlSW5zZW5zaXRpdmVIYXNo
TWFwndHZ72dFzgADAAB4cHcMP0AAAAAAABAAAAAAeHEAfgAJeHB4
X-MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
Content-Length: 13
Connection: close

When ABC case
```

I always use curl, because that is the tool referenced by various forums.

Is there a tool that can test RESTful or HTTP inside the Mule ESB Eclipse platform? This might alleviate some testing situations. So far I could not find any, but I can find curl implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you pls try with the following configuration removing `contentType="application/json"` in http inbound with `mimeType="application/json"` and `', payload.get(\047uid\047): '` from set payload and check :-

```xml
<json:object-to-json-transformer name="Object_to_JSON" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
<flow doc:name="HelloWorldFlow1" name="HelloWorldFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." mimeType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081"  path="mule/getBalance"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.HashMap"/>
    <choice doc:name="Determine Bank" >
        <when expression="#[message.payload.get('uid') == 'ABC']">
            <set-payload value="When ABC case" doc:name="Friendly Bank"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-payload value="#['Default case, payload:  ' + payload + ', payload.get(\047uid\047): ' + message.payload.id]" doc:name="SOF Bank"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```